# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm having a strange problem with my code. There is an object that comes from an API call where videos are stored and I need to add the number of videos on the website. But sometimes there can be "null" coming from API call and obviously, I don't have to show the length of the null value.

As I wrote this code which works when I try on editors, but when I use it on my project it gives an error Cannot convert undefined or null to object. Can anyone give me an idea or hint of what I'm doing wrong? And sorry if I explained unclearly, this is my very first post here. Thank you!

```
const object = {
  background_video: null,
  vimeo_branded: 'video url',
  vimeo_unbranded: "video url"
}

const removeFalsyElement = object => {
  let sum = 0;
  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    if (object[key]) {
      sum += 1;
    }
  });
  return sum;
};

console.log(removeFalsyElement(object)) // output should be 2.
```

Comment: I get output as 2. BTW this example doesn't seem to reproduce the issue you are facing. Please post a [mre].

Comment: I agree with @kiner_shah. To elaborate a bit, from you error in the title it seems that in a different environment (when the actual API is called) you end up hitting some code that tries to convert an undefined or null value to an object. So you would have to identify the part of the code that throws that error and post that part, or post the whole part of the code where the API response is received and where the response is used. It might just be that the whole response body is empty and the code produces an undefined or null from there on, which your code does not handle correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The Object.keys method expects an object always. if we pass null we would get the above mentioned error

```
const removeFalsyElement = (object = {}) => {//default value for object in case it is null. Object.keys needs an object always


let sum = 0;
  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    if (object[key]) {
      sum += 1;
    }
  });
  return sum;
};
```